# How do I use nicematrix package in Sphinx documentation?

Tags: miktex, python, nicematrix, sphinx, restructured-text

I'm trying to incorporate nicematrix functionalities into my Sphinx documentation. I have MiKTeX and I've intalled the nicematrix package.

In my conf.py file, I added this:

```
latex_elements  ={'preamble': r'''\usepackage{nicematrix}'''}
```

In my .rst file, I tried a simple example from nicematrix documentation (https://texlive.mycozy.space/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf):

```
    .. math::
    \NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 1pt}
    \begin{pNiceMatrix}
    \frac12 & -\frac12 \\
    \frac13 & \frac14 \\
    \end{pNiceMatrix}
```

But this is the error I get:

```
(C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\ums
a.fd)

(C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\ums
b.fd)

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ag \begin {split}\NiceMatrixOptions
                                                  {cell-space-limits = 1pt} ...
l.21 \end{pNiceMatrix}\end{split}


! LaTeX Error: Environment pNiceMatrix undefined.
```

I'm guessing its because ..math:: refers to amsmath. How do I refer to the nicematrix module then?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the generated latex file, does it have `\usepackage{nicematrix}` ?